# Adding Authorization request header in Stripe Dashboard Webhooks endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, stripe-payments

Is there anyway to add Authorization request header when configuring

[image: Webhook endpoint in Stripe Dashboard]?

In CLI, adding the `-H "Authorization: ..."` on `stripe listen` command does the trick. Just wondering if this is also available on the Stripe Dashboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only authentication Stripe supports for sending webhooks to your server right now is  Basic Auth in the URL, so e.g. you'd add the URL in the Dashboard as :

```
https://username:password@example.com/webhook-endpoint
```

There's no way to specify headers, that's something stripe-cli supports for assisting in local development but not part of the general webhook endpoint configuration.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your input @karllekko. That's definitely something I would have to think about on my application implementation.

Comment: This worked, on the wp-engine test environment, need HTTP auth and that stop stripe webhook to stop, so preparing webhook with above format solved the problem.